# Parse JSON data inside from occurrence of script tag using SimpleHtmlDom - PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using simple html dom to parse a link that contains two script tags with type=application/ld+json.

The target website structure is like below,

```
// tag that I want to parse
<script type="application/ld+json">
Some JSON Data
</script>


// tag that I **do not want** to parse
<script type="application/ld+json">
Some JSON Data
</script>
```

Now as I showed above I just want to parse the data inside the first , For this I am using following code

```
foreach($html->find('script[type="application/ld+json"]',0) as $name)
{
   echo $name->innertext;
}
```

As I am trying to extract the first occurrence of  by specifying "0" in find() function but that give me the following error.

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\htmldom\example\example_basic_selector.php on line 14
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong or  how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: So are you saying that without `,0`, it works and shows you the inner text of both of those script elements? If not, then that would mean your selector doesn’t match the elements to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe exactly. If I dont use "0" or anything else than it shows me the data from both script tags.

Comment: I guess trying to _loop_ over this in case where you requested only one specific element to be returned, is wrong to begin with. `find('foo')` returns an _array_, `find('foo', 0)` returns one specific element. Does `$script = $html->find('script[type="application/ld+json"]',0); echo $script->innertext;` get you what you need?

Comment: should I tell you the var_dump result or try the above code you posted just now?

Comment: Nigel’s answer already confirms my suspicion, so just use their code and it should work.

Comment: it worked thanks both of you :).

Comment: hi there Faisal i Shani i am very very glad that it finally works. This is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the index of the instance you want, you only get that element back and not a list, so the loop isn't required (in fact is the problem)...

```
$json = $html->find('script[type="application/ld+json"]',0);
echo $json->innertext;
```

Just for reference, the code from `find()`...

```
    // return nth-element or array
    if (is_null($idx)) return $found;
    else if ($idx<0) $idx = count($found) + $idx;
    return (isset($found[$idx])) ? $found[$idx] : null;
```